# How to redirect drupal 8.3.2 https to http

Tags: php, drupal-8

Need help in redirecting https to http in drupal 8.3.2

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>

php_flag engine off

</IfModule>
```

so how am i suppose to redirect

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question.

Also you should add code you already tried (as far as i can see there are no redirect-commands at all in your code).

Comment: i triend 2 ways one is in settings.php by creating $base_url and trying 301 redirect it didnt work

Comment: 2nd way was $conf way which didnt work so i reverted back told code as default

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [.htaccess generator](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/) This will help you to create new .htaccess file and will work as you want.

Comment: The generator has no HTTPS references which makes it useless to solve this issue.